# Menu is not opening on keydown.enter when used inside mat-expansion panel header in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-material-6, event-propagation

I am using the mat-menu with mat-expansion-panel where there is an expansion panel, i placed the mat-icon at the end of header of expansion panel, on click of this icon it will open a menu item. on click of header of expansion panel it opens the panel description . This is the desired behaviour, this is working using mouse click.

But this is not same when i navigate to icon by keydown.enter(using tab), it was collapsing the panel when i tab into icon and press enter, somehow i fixed it with event.stopPropagation() and by returning false. But it is not opening the menu item on press of enter on the icon. Here is the stackblitz link [menuwithExpansionPanel](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oyz5pr). Please help me in resolving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your button should be the trigger, not the icon:

```
<span class="export-to-csv-span">
  <button mat-button variant="icon-button"
      [matMenuTriggerFor]="exportAsMenu"
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
      (keydown.enter)="$event.stopPropagation()"
      (keydown.space)="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <mat-icon>vertical_align_bottom</mat-icon>
  </button>
</span>
```